# Installing PygraphViz on Windows, Python 2.6

Tags: python, c, windows, installation, graphviz

Anybody out there has successfully installed PygraphViz on Windows?

Since there is not an official [release for Windows](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygraphviz/), I'm trying to build it myself, but it fails to compile. I'm not the [first one](https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/ticket/117) to [face this issue](http://groups.google.com/group/networkx-discuss/browse_thread/thread/36786fe98e7dcd72), but I could not find an answer.

This is the console output:

```
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pygraphviz-0.99.1>c:\python26\python.exe setup.py
install
library_path=C:/Program Files/Graphviz2.26.3/lib/debug/dll
include_path=C:/Program Files/Graphviz2.26.3/include/graphviz
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W
3 /GS- /DNDEBUG "-IC:/Program Files/Graphviz2.26.3/include/graphviz" -Ic:\python
26\include -Ic:\python26\PC /Tcpygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.
6\Release\pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.obj
graphviz_wrap.c
warning: I don't know what to do with 'runtime_library_dirs': ['C:/Program Files
/Graphviz2.26.3/lib/debug/dll']
error: don't know how to set runtime library search path for MSVC++
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Python2.6 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with PygraphViz 0.99.1 and graphviz 2.26.3. Any ideas... anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what worked for me in Python 2.7. I assume it should work similarly in Python 2.6.
Precondition: Install mingw32 (included in pythonxy distrib if you're using it), Graphviz

1) Download pygraphviz sources

2) Edit setup.py to change paths to smth like

```
library_path=r"c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\bin"
include_path=r"c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\include\graphviz"
```

Note that it's \bin, not \lib. Linking with libs didn't work for me.

3) run `python setup.py build -c mingw32`

Result of step 3:

```
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pygraphviz-1.1>python setup.py build -c mingw32
library_path=c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\bin
include_path=c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\include\graphviz
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
C:\MinGW32-xy\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall "-Ic:\Program Files (x86)\G
raphviz 2.28\include\graphviz" -Ic:\Python27\include -Ic:\Python27\PC -c pygraph
viz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.o
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c: In function 'agattr_label':
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2855:5: warning: return makes integer from pointer wi
thout a cast
writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pygraphviz\_graphviz.def
C:\MinGW32-xy\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\py
graphviz\graphviz_wrap.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pygraphviz\_graphviz.def "
-Lc:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\bin" -Lc:\Python27\libs -Lc:\Python27\PCb
uild "-Wl,-Rc:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\bin" -lcgraph -lcdt -lpython27
-lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz\_graphviz.pyd
```

4) copy the result from the just built lib.win32-2.7 (single sub-folder called `pygraphviz`)  into your Python's site-packages folder

Enjoy!

Comment: How did you installed MinGW32-xy? I am using MinGW Minimalist GNU for Windows and I have problems with it. When I try to install pygraphviz I get this error: cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'.

Comment: I don't remember, but I think it was part of the pythonxy distro.

Comment: mingw32 with gcc 4.6.x wont work with Python 2.7.2 distutils due to the missing -mno-cygwin. It is a known Python core issue. ptyhonxy ships with 4.5.x still.

Comment: @Ηλίας, you unzip the source code, and it is just in the folder

Answer (score 18):

I appreciate this may be an obsolete thread by now, but to update it for others currently hitting this wall, the installer at Christoph Gohlke's [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz) has just worked for me..

Comment: I was unable to get this to work. Ran graphviz-2.38.msi then ran pygraphviz‑1.2.win32‑py2.7.exe. Still get the import error 'requires pygraphviz'

Comment: Have you added your python distribution path to your Environmental Variables? If so you might want to open up a new question to resolve.

Comment: +Inf, you're a life-saver

Answer (score 4):

I've just ran into the same problem myself today. It isn't much of an answer, but I read in their [FAQ](http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/reference/faq.html):

> Q:
>
> How do I compile pygraphviz under
> Windows? And why don’t you distribute
> a pygraphviz Windows installer?
>
> A:
>
> We don’t have Windows development
> machines but would like to have
> pygraphviz work on all platforms. If
> you have success with Windows or would
> be willing to help test and distribute
> a Windows installer please drop us a
> note.
>
> See also ticket 67:
> https://networkx.lanl.gov/ticket/67

This, together with multiple unanswered pleas for help on various forums, mailing lists and newsgroups, lead me to believe that running PyGraphviz on Windows isn't something that can be done simply today.

So I did the next obvious thing (*) and fired up my Ubuntu on top of VirtualBox to create Graphviz graphs with Python. Curiously, it fails to install from source on Ubuntu as well, unless you have Graphviz itself installed from source, but it can be installed from a pre-built package with `sudo apt-get python-pygraphviz`.

So now I'm a happy pygraphviz user. Or at least 90% happy. PGV shows a `os.popen3` deprecation warning on Python 2.6, and a [18-month-old ticket](https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/changeset/1073/pygraphviz/trunk/pygraphviz/agraph.py) with a patch on this issue still hasn't been incorporated. Argh!

(*) I do it more and more lately...

Comment: Actually you are looking at the fixed code at https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/changeset/1073/pygraphviz/trunk/pygraphviz/agraph.py  Apparently the version of pygraphviz you installed is older than that fix.  You can get the latest version at /http://networkx.lanl.gov/download/pygraphviz/

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the 'runtime_library_dirs' parameter from the **extension** dictionary in on line 147 in setup.py, your error message goes away.  However, it can't find cgraph.lib.  If you change your settings to

```
library_path=r'C:\Program Files\Graphviz2.26.3\lib\debug\lib'
```

everything complies and installs.  You can import the modules, but the moment you try and access anything, it bombs out.  In looking at the source for GraphViz, it appears that the windows version is C#/.NET - perhaps that is the source of our problems?

Answer (score 1):

Hat the same problem and I finally got it to work!  The problem was actually in Python's msvc9compiler.py (yes you do need VS8's vc9 to compile, too).  The error comes on line 698 in the function runtime_library_dir_option().  Instead of having it throw an error, have it return the same string as library_dir_option():

```
def runtime_library_dir_option(self, dir):
    return "/LIBPATH:" + dir
```

Then compile and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can try to use `easy_install` and avoid compiling.  I installed "distribute", a fork of easy_install.  But it also requires pkg-config, and you either have to compile that or get an older version.  Furthermore, you also have to add pkg-config to the application path.

Comment: This only works if they supply an easy_install-able version for windows, which it sounds like they don't. Although this post is from May...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile pygraphviz under windows with the following setup:

Windows 7,
WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3,
Graphviz2.38,
microsoft visual c++ 2008 express edition,
pygraphvize 1.3 dev

in setup.py changed lines 35 and 36 to:

include_dirs = r"C:\Program Files\Graphviz2.38\include"
library_dirs = r"C:\Program Files\Graphviz2.38\lib\release\lib"

The compilation works and you get a working pygraphviz python module.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: I did the same thing, but it throws out a bunch of linkage errors, do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, Python 2.7 32 bit, PyGraphViz 2.38, VCForPython27, Windows 10 64 bit.

First, install VCForPython27, see http://aka.ms/vcpython27.

Then, execute the following command, so that `distutils.msvc9compiler` can find the VC compiler. (This needs Administrator privilege. And if your Windows is 32 bit, you need to adjust the registry key.)

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VC -v productdir -t REG_SZ -d "%LocalAppData%\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0" -f
```

Finally, install PyGraphViz.

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\include
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\lib\release\lib
pip install pygraphviz
```