# I am trying to install pygraphviz but received the following error

Tags: networkx, pygraphviz

I am trying to install pygraphviz, I tried to do so with the following command but unfortunately it is not working. Can anyone help how to fix it?

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pygraphviz-1.2>python setup.py build -c mingw32
    library_path=c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\bin
    include_path=c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\include\graphviz
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz\agraph.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz\graphviz.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz\version.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz\tests
    copying pygraphviz\tests\test.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz\tests
    copying pygraphviz\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz\tests
    copying pygraphviz\tests\attributes.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz\test
    copying pygraphviz\tests\graph.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz\tests
    copying pygraphviz\tests\layout_draw.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz\tes

    copying pygraphviz\tests\unicode.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pygraphviz\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pygraphviz
    gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall "-Ic:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\include
    raphviz" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c
     build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.o
    error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing gcc C compiler?  There are some tips for compiling PyGraphviz with Windows at [Installing PygraphViz on Windows, Python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798858/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-python-2-6)